# Russian loan words in English

Tags: loan-words

I have a task to make a research paper about Russian loan-words in English and can't find any informative material. Could you help me, please? I spent hours googling and got almost nothing. Is this topic so unknown? I know that the opposite topic is covered rather well, there are many work about English loan words in Russian.. but unfortunately i have another topic - about Russian words in English. 
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what search terms were you trying in your hours of Googling?  I tried "Russian loan words in English" and got a good page of results including the Wikipedia link: [List of English words of Russian origin - Wikipedia](https://www.google.com.my/search?q=russian+loan+word+in+English&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_FYHVffVE463oQS314CgAg) Also: http://www.english-for-students.com/Russian-Loan-Words.html

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. If you want a list of Russian loanwords, the links Jim has provided should be useful; StackExchange is not a discussion forum, and our format is very ill-suited to lists. If this is a request for resources, the [Meta site](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Russian_origin) which may be useful.

Be warned, however, that most of these have not been fully assimilated into English; they are mostly Russian words which are familiar as names for Russian entities. Only a handful have lost their specifically Russian reference and become "naturalized". I would include these:

- balaclava
- beluga
- bridge (the card game)
- intelligentsia
- mammoth
- pogrom
- sable
- taiga
- troika (in the administrative sense)
- tundra
- vodka
- ukase

Comment: Not gulag? It's similar to vodka in that its Russian origin is obvious but I have heard it being used in contexts that had nothing to do with Russia.

Comment: Just a note, not everyone recognizes these words... as an AmE speaker, I don't know what taiga or ukase mean... and have only a vague sense of balaclava and troika.

Comment: @Catija I think that there are many words that the typical English speaker isn't familiar with and that Russian loan-words aren't necessarily less well known than loan-words from other languages. [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/) includes a an estimate of how commonly used a word is, so it tends to be my go-to dictionary.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree... but Stoney is implying that the words on that list have been assimilated into English and I was just noting that I disagree with some of them. I would argue that I have a very good vocabulary and **still** don't know what they mean... so they can't have been that assimilated.

Comment: @Catija I don't know if popularity/commonality is the only measure of assimilation. Taiga is one word that I'm very familiar with and it means something very specific that doesn't have a comparable word (that I know of) in English. It's used commonly among folks that talk about biomes (and Magic the Gathering players ;)) even though it doesn't come up often in normal conversation.

Answer (score 1):

To StoneyB's list, I'd add the following:

- Babushka, for a headscarf, not a grandmother. Stress is on the second syllable in English (ba-BUSH-ka)
- Glasnost, usually recognized as the period of time during Gorbachev's term
- Duma, for the Russian legislature
- Perestroika - and maybe only people who lived through the 80's and 90's will remember this one
- Sputnik and Mir - known as the names of the satellites and space station only
- Ruble

Comment: I removed *intelligentsia*, which is Latin in origin, but would also question *Duma* and *Ruble* as loanwords, as these refer to specific Russian institutions— we do not refer to just any legislature as a *duma*, nor just any currency as a *ruble*. Similarly, *Sputnik* and *Mir* are names; *Sputnik* is used metaphorically, but I have never heard such a use of *Mir*.